# Where to initiate a side effect action in an ngrx app?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In this [ngrx example](http://ngrx.github.io/example-app/#/), the START action is initiated in the `search` method of the [container](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/find-book-page.ts) smart component.

If I want to list all the books from a category without the user typing in any string or selecting any category (a default category of 'technical' can be used), where should I dispatch the SEARCH action? I'm looking for an initial effect without the user taking any action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

- set up a SearchByCategory effect and its reducer.
- **in collection-page.ts, in a ngOnInit function**, something like

```js
this.book$ = store.dispatch( {
                   type: DISPLAY_CATEGORY,
                   payload: { category: 'technical' }
             });
```

Take this as a hint since I have not tested it (for some reason, vscode throws plenty of declaration errors and no time correct them today). However, I do exactly that in my current project, so it should work.

Comment: I added a little more clarification to the question.

Comment: That is a good solution. Is it possible to initiate the action of getting the books from the server in the ```effect``` itself?

Comment: That is leaking the side effects into the reducers. Loading the initial state should be outside of the reducers. I don't know whether the ```observable``` can auto initiate a call with a timer a good pattern.

Comment: in effects/collections.ts, the first effect opens the connection to the database. You could try to dispatch the search after the connection is established. I guess you'd have to erase that "dispatch: false" parameter that I didn't now of till now (quite interesting btw).

Comment: (sorry, I saw your point myself and was rewriting my answer as you were writing yours)

Comment: I see there are three approaches to solve this problem. First one is what you suggested which I think is the elegant. After the components are loaded, a call is made to get the data. The second is to use a timer in the container or initiate the call to the service from the ```effect``` itself as your suggested above in the comment.